# Match several repeated names / strings

Tags: r, string, if-statement, match

I am new (and self-taught) to R so please bear with me.

My data is something like:

```
variable    value
asdf    3
sdfg    2
dfgh    5
fghj    6
ghjk    6
fghj    7
qwer    8
wert    5
erty    2
```

I need to apply an exponential function to the values of all rows. However, rows with variable names equal to “asdf”, “wert” or “fghj” should remain constant.

I have tried to do it directly

```
   if ( (c("asdf", "wert", "fghj")) %in% df$variable {
      df$value <- df$value
    } else if {
      df$value <- exp(df$value)
    }
```

As it didn't work, I tried to create a vector pointing out those rows that contain the names as a stepping stone (also unsuccesfully).

```
tomatch <- c("asdf", "wert", "fghj")

exporder <- grep("tomatch", df$variable)
```

I had a look to the `match()` function but it only reports the first match but not the following, and I have also applied the `%in%` but I can't figure out why it is not working.

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you probably want `ifelse`.

Comment: specifically `df <- transform(df,value=ifelse(variable %in% ...,value,exp(value)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
totrans <- !(df$variable %in% c("asdf", "wert", "fghj"))
df$value[totrans] <- exp(df$value[totrans])
```

or

```
df$value <- ifelse(df$variable %in% c("asdf", "wert", "fghj"), 
    df$value, exp(df$value))
```

The problem with your `%in%` and `if` is that your `%in%` parameters as flipped (`%in%` is not Commutative) and `if` is not a vectorized operation in R. The `ifelse()` function acts like a vectorized ternary operator.